# trino cast as row case-insensitive

Tags: sql, presto, trino

I have a sql like this

```sql
select
    cast (cast("cf00a399af"."2be9fc3823" as json) as row(cityId bigint, city varchar)) as 
    address,
    count(0) as num
from  ygg_dev."913852142333198336" cf00a399af
group by "cf00a399af"."2be9fc3823"
```

and my result is this

| address | num |
| --- | --- |
| {cityid=44, city=石家庄市} | 1 |
| {cityid=23, city=天津市} | 1 |
| {cityid=1318, city=泉州市} | 1 |
| {cityid=0, city=} | 9 |
| {cityid=1274, city=福州市} | 1 |
| {cityid=1318, city=泉州市} | 1 |
| {cityid=2, city=北京市} | 1 |
| {cityid=1318, city=泉州市} | 2 |

the result cityid is a lowercase letter but i want it case-insensitive with cityId
how could i do ?

the java object

```java
@Data
public class AddressInputValue implements java.io.Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @ApiModelProperty("省ID")
    private long provinceId;

    @ApiModelProperty("省名称")
    private String province;

    @ApiModelProperty("市ID")
    private long cityId;

    @ApiModelProperty("市名称")
    private String city;

    @ApiModelProperty("县ID")
    private long countyId;

    @ApiModelProperty("县名称")
    private String county;

    @ApiModelProperty("详细地址")
    private String address;

    @ApiModelProperty("经纬度坐标")
    private MapPoint point;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"By default" row field names as columns are case insensitive:

```sql
select r.cityId c1, r.CITYID c2, r.cityid c3
from (select cast(row(1, 'cityname') as row(cityId bigint, city varchar)) r) ;
```

Output:

| c1 | c2 | c3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |

**UPD**

If you want to have case-sensitive output - convert it to `map` of jsons:

```sql
select map(array['cityId', 'city'], array[cast(r.cityId as json), cast(r.city as json)])
from (select cast(row(1, 'cityname') as row (cityId bigint, city varchar)) r);
```

Output:

| _col0 |
| --- |
| {city="cityname", cityId=1} |

Additionally you can convert the whole map to json:

```sql
select cast(
    map(array['cityId', 'city'], array[cast(r.cityId as json), cast(r.city as json)])
    as json)
from (select cast(row(1, 'cityname') as row(cityId bigint, city varchar)) r);
```

Output:

| _col0 |
| --- |
| {"city":"cityname","cityId":1} |

Comment: i want to keey it a row type  and the name is cityId  and provinceId  because my java object attr is cityId and provinceId  not cityid

Comment: @dapisces see the update.